# How to get the connection interval between peripheral (BLE device) and central (iPhone)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a BLE project and the peripheral is a BLE device and central is an iPhone (iOS-10.3.1). I read quite a few posts, they all mentioned that the minimum connection interval for iPhone is 30ms. However, I just wonder, is that possible to get the "connection interval" in the app programmatically? My development environment is XCode8.3.2 + Swift3.1. The BLE device uses nRF51 chip. I will be really grateful if you could post some code or direct me to the right method that I should look into. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get or set the connection interval through Core Bluetooth framework. But you can check the connection interval from Peripheral side using sniffer tool.

Also you can send the connection parameter update from Pheriperal to iOS.

Refer this link for more info (Page no 22)

https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

Comment: hi, dude, thanks for the answer, I checked that guide and i think you are right, re the sniffer method and "send the connection parameter update", could you give me some more details or point me in the right directions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the Android phone, enable Bluetooth HCI snoop logging in Developer settings.

A log file will be created in the internal sdcard folder. Open it in wireshark. It will show you all low level signaling data sent and received over Bluetooth, including BLE connection parameters such as connection interval.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is super helpful!

Comment: @infinity_coding7 I'm glad! Re-reading your question, my answer doesn't sound that intuitive, but the hidden suggestion is that now Android can behave as a BLE peripheral so, we can use it to help diagnose iOS central behavior.